# How do you fix "connection.play is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So, I've looked far and wide for code and I compiled all of them into a single thing that that worked, but can't play audio files. So what I wanted to do, is play audiofile.wav on a discord channel. So this is the code I've tried.

```
function playFunction(arguments, receivedMessage) {
  var isReady = true;
  if (isReady = true) {
    isReady = false;
    var voiceChannel = receivedMessage.member.voiceChannel;
    var connection = voiceChannel.join();
    voiceChannel.join().then(connection=> {console.log("Test")}).catch(err => console.log(err));
    voiceChannel.join().then(connection=> {}).catch(err => console.log(err));
    const dispatcher = connection.play('./audiofile.wav');
   dispatcher.on("end", end => {voiceChannel.leave();})
  } 
}
```

So the error I get, as I said in the title is:

```
const dispatcher = connection.play('./audiofile.wav');
                                  ^

TypeError: connection.play is not a function
    at playFunction (rootpath\bot.js:88:35)
    at processCommand (rootpath\bot.js:73:9)
    at Client.client.on (rootpath\bot.js:22:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Client.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle rootpath\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (rootpath\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (rootpath\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (rootpath\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (rootpath\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
```

root path is just the path to my bot.js and other files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method "play()" does not exist in that context. I think you need to use "playFile()".

```js
const dispatcher = connection.playFile('./audiofile.wav');
```

More information: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceConnection?scrollTo=playFile